# Starting nginx on Ubuntu 12.04 with init.d and custom configuration file

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx

I have an nginx configuration specific to a project I'm currently working on (Django, to be precise).

It looks like the "right" way to start nginx on Ubuntu is

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

However, I want to supply a custom configuration file. Normally I'd do this in the following way:

```
sudo nginx -c /my/project/config/nginx.conf
```

Looking at the `init.d/nginx` file, it doesn't look like there the `start` command passes in any arguments, so I can't do

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start -c /my/project/config/nginx.conf
```

What's the best way to solve my problem?

Comment: try `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx -s start -c /my/project/config/nginx.conf`

Comment: I get the standard init.d error message:

Usage: nginx {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status|configtest}

Comment: You can hardcode the custom configuration path in the `/etc/init.d/nginx` just edit the variable `NGINX_CONF_FILE="/my/project/config/nginx.conf"`. Then you can just do `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start` to start it. I am not sure though if this is a good way.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm hoping there's a better way - I'd prefer not to have to patch a builtin like this directly. Unfortunately this just seems like an init.d limitation...

Answer (score 1):

init.d is not the right supervisor to use on Ubuntu anymore, you should use Upstart. Put this in /etc/init/nginx.conf and you will be able to start/stop it with `sudo start nginx` and `sudo stop nginx`:

```
description "nginx http daemon"
author "George Shammas"

start on (filesystem and net-device-up IFACE=lo)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

env DAEMON=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -c /my/project/config/nginx.conf
env PID=/usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid

expect fork
respawn
respawn limit 10 5

pre-start script
    $DAEMON -t
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
            then exit $?
    fi
end script

exec $DAEMON
```